# How to Use build-stability-plugin in sonar

Tags: plugins, hudson, sonarqube

I downloaded build-stability-plugin and put it in my plugins folder and re-started the sonar server.
I can't see anything in the dashboard of projects related to build-stability-plugin.
Is there anything else i have to do in pom.xml file of projects. I don't have any idea to make this working. What i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin), you'll see that this plugin provides a widget. This means that you have to edit an existing dashboard (or create a new one) to add this widget if you want to see something in Sonar.

Also, as mentioned in the documentation, do not forget to configure the plugin (in the settings), if a user and a password are required.