# SonarQube Build Stability plugin doesn't appear to be running

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Configuration:

- SonarQube 5.1.2 with Build Stability plugin 1.3
- Jenkins: 1.614
- Maven: 3.2.2

I am attempting to use Build Stability with SonarQube and Jenkins.  I added the Build Stability plugin to the `${SONARQUBE_HOME}/extensions/plugins` directory and restarted the server.  I see that the plugin is enabled in the SonarQube log.  I added the Build Stability widget to the default project dashboard as described in documentation and [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454145/944849).  Since our Jenkins instance is secured via LDAP, I also supplied credentials for a user with permissions to access Jenkins.  I put the Jenkins job URL in the `ciManagement` section of the POM.

Then I ran a build and fed metrics to SonarQube with a Jenkins Post Build action (calls mvn sonar:sonar).  The build is successful and I see all other data in SonarQube - test results, coverage, etc.  The job logs (which have debugging enabled) show all of the various sensors running.  However, I do not see any data for the Build Stability plugin when I view my project in SonarQube.  I also do not see an attempt to execute the Build Stability plugin in the job logs.  I was hoping to see something like this in the job log (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22680152/944849)):

```
[INFO] [05:17:18.108] CI URL: Jenkins:http://<host>/job/<job-name>/
```

but there was nothing related to Build Stability.  I then tried adding the URL to the project configuration in SonarQube, thinking perhaps I had the POM wrong.  No difference.  I have tested the Jenkins job URL and it works.

I also enabled debug logging on the SonarQube server.  I see log entries for the job being run, but nothing specific to individual plugins.

At this point I'd be happy even to see a 401/403 error because that's farther than where I am now.

How do I get this plugin to run?  What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While hunting for other possible solutions I found the `-Dsonar.verbose` option.  I thought that might give me more clues, so added it to the Sonar configuration in Jenkins and re-ran the build.  And now I see:

```
[INFO] [12:16:20.128] Sensor Build Stability
[INFO] [12:16:20.128] CI URL: https://host.com/job/jobName/
[WARN] [12:16:20.130] Unknown CiManagement system or incorrect URL: https://host.com/job/jobName/
[INFO] [12:16:20.130] Sensor Build Stability (done) | time=2ms
```

I had forgotten to put the "Jenkins:" part in front of the URL when I configured the Job URL in SonarQube.

It appears that BuildStability only works if the Job URL is explicitly configured.  The plugin does not seem to retrieve the information from the `ciManagement` section of the POM (aggregator or parent), despite what the documentation says.